# Oneplus 2 Soft-Brick

Tags: custom-roms, unbricking, 7.0-nougat, oneplus-two

I bought a Oneplus 2, two years ago and it was running quite well. A couple of months ago, I decided that I didn't like the way that Oxygen OS 3 was running so I decided to root my phone.

I successfully rooted it, added TWRP Recovery and added Resseruction Remix. It was working perfectly for the last few months without any problems. However, when I rebooted it yesterday, out of the blue, it went into a boot loop.

I can see the Oneplus logo and the boot animation that I have, but the animation runs indefinitely. I did some research and I believe this is known as soft-bricking. I tried to clear the Cache and Dalvik from my recovery but that doesn't work either.

How do I get my phone to work properly? I don't have a recent backup and would prefer not to factory reset my phone.

Comment: flash the rom again preferably a previous build which was working perfect

Comment: yeah i did that and it works well now. It is running Oxygen OS though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flash the rom again preferably a previous build which was working perfect.

Dirty flash will do the work but if it doesn't then clean flash it.